# AssertionError while merging cells with xlwt (Python)

Tags: python, xlwt

I'm using xlwt to do some Excel sheets generation, but it appears that whenever I try to merge cells in line, Python throws an AssertionError, even for a code as simple as:

```
import xlwt

wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding = 'latin-1')
ws = wb.add_sheet('hey')

ws.write_merge(0,0,8,0,"hi")

wb.save("test.xls")
```

Could anyone please help me on this? Did I miss something? Thank you ever so much.

Comment: (How) Did you install xlwt python module?

Comment: I did indeed (otherwise I wouldn't even have this error), and I used pip for this matter.

Also worth noting, the column merging works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR;

Perhaps your call should be:

```
ws.write_merge(0,0,0,8,"hi")
```

Explaination:
Fuller stack trace:

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-c6b20b7b1b27> in <module>()
----> 1 ws.write_merge(0,0,8,0)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlwt/Worksheet.pyc in write_merge(self, r1, r2, c1, c2, label, style)
   1110 
   1111     def write_merge(self, r1, r2, c1, c2, label="", style=Style.default_style):
-> 1112         assert 0 <= c1 <= c2 <= 255
   1113         assert 0 <= r1 <= r2 <= 65535
   1114         self.write(r1, c1, label, style)
```

I believe (I'm not sure but please correct me if I am wrong here) `write_merge` is used to merge multiple cells (portion of worksheet) into a single cell. The arguments are (I guess!) start_row, end_row, start_col, end_col resp. It seems natural to me that `c1 <= c2 and r1 <= r2` must hold true to have a real portion to merge into a single cell.

Comment: Oh my God I just understood I was putting the parameters wrong from the start. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

the arguments of write_merge method should be in the following order to work:
sheet.write_merge(start_row,end_row,start_col,end_col,"Cells Value")
ex:

```
ws.write_merge(0,0,0,8,"hi")
```